# What's a counterexample to $f(a) =f(b)$ for non-convex sets?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function on a convex open set $S \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\partial_1 = 0 \;\forall x \in S$. Now let $a,b \in S$ such that $a-b = (c, 0, \dots,0)$, $c\ne0$. Then $f(a)=f(b)$. This follows easily from the mean value theorem which says $\exists c \in \gamma$ such that $f(b)-f(a)= \nabla f (c) \cdot (b-a)$ where $\gamma $ is the line segment joining $a$ and $b$. Now I want to ask if it holds on non-convex sets, where the mean value theorem no longer holds. I tried to produce a counterexample but I could not see any obvious ones. If there aren’t any how could I prove it?

Comment: A disconnected set is non-convex.

Comment: @Arthur The question doesn't mention disconnected sets. Why are you saying this?

Comment: @lisyarus The OP wants an example where the theorem breaks down if we don't require $S$ to be convex. They are having trouble coming up with one. I'm telling them that they could look for an example where $S$ is not connected, because I think that's easier than trying to find an example on a connected, non-convex $S$ (even though that's possible as well).

Comment: @Arthur I am sorry, I misinterpreted your comment as indicating some error in the post, and not as an answer to the question. Why don't you answer it, then? I would be happy to see a connected example, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple example (the simplest?), set $n = 1$, take $S = (0,1)\cup (1, 2)$ and let $f:S\to \Bbb R$ be defined as
$$
f(x) = \cases{0 & if $x<1$\\1& if $x>1$}
$$
It is everywhere continuous and differentiable, and the derivative is equal to $0$, yet it takes two different values.

For a connected counterexample (although using the same idea as above), set $n = 2$ and let $S$ be the plane minus the origin and the positive $y$-axis. Define $f:S\to \Bbb R$ as
$$
f(x, y) = \cases{0 & if $y \leq 0$\\y^2 & if $y>0$ and $x>0$\\-y^2 & if $y>0$ and $x<0$}
$$
This is everywhere continuously differentiable, and the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is $0$ on all of $S$. And yet, $f(-1, 1) = -1 \neq 1 = f(1, 1)$.